# Best practices for handling a useful but off-topic question

Tags: discussion, old-questions

I have an [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14981928/syntax-highlighting-at-command-line-as-i-type) that I naively didn't realize was off-topic when I asked it.  It was closed a short while after being asked and answered.  Since then, I can see there have been a decent number of views, and two favorites, indicating that the question is useful, though probably better-suited for a site like [superuser](https://superuser.com/).

Since:

- A question past 60 days cannot be migrated (except by developers under very special circumstances)
- The question clearly isn't appropriate for SO
- The question has up votes (deletion isn't possible)

My only options are to leave it as-is, or leave the existing question and post anew on superuser.  The latter makes sense, but I didn't want to be accused of cross-posting.

Comment: The answer has upvotes, you couldn't delete it even if you wanted to.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, good point, question updated.

Comment: Developers can migrate a post without being subject to the 60-day restriction. This was used to migrate old SO-specific posts from MSE to here during the great meta split.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi What is the process for getting developers to migrate a post? Is this a heavy burden such that a question should be subject to increased scrutiny before being deemed worthy of being moved?

Comment: @TTT You use chat

Comment: Well, isn't this embarrassing. Now that you brought it up, it looks like the question has been removed.

Comment: Wait, why in the world was it deleted now as a result of this meta discussion?  Off-topic or not, deleting it when I've brought up a discussion about its usefulness seems to go against the spirit of this community.

Comment: @TTT agreed. Not sure why it was deleted now.

Comment: I will now spend the rest of my days never knowing what the question was.

Comment: Update:  Post has been un-deleted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Leave it as-is. Being closed in this case just means it won't get any more answers. With upvotes on both the question and the answer, it's not going to get automatically deleted. It could get deleted by community action but I'm not sure how likely that is. In any case, that's really not your concern at this point; you put some content out into the world, and other people interacted with it to the point where you no longer have direct control over what happens to it.

Sounds like what you really want to ask is whether you can ask your question again on SU. If your question here had been downvoted and deleted, you wouldn't have to ask; it wouldn't be cross-posting. But you're in a bind because your question was both upvoted and closed.

Here's the thing: Is this *really* a good, on-topic question for SU?

- Someone left you a comment pointing to [a SU question](https://superuser.com/q/304211/374604) that's very, very similar to yours. Would your question be closed on SU as a duplicate? If so, don't cross post it.
- If the community had felt your question was a good, off-topic question for SU, they might have migrated it at the time instead of closing it as off-topic. The general rule is that only high-quality questions that would be well-received at the target site should be migrated. Ask yourself why your question wasn't migrated in the first place; would it be well-received on SU? If not, don't cross post it.
- You've let this question lie for almost two years. Why dig it back up now? The upvotes only show that some people are finding this old Q&A useful, despite it being closed. Where's the problem? Are you frustrated at having a closed question in your profile? Are you attracted to the idea that this question could earn you more reputation on SU than it has earned on SO? Are you just bored? If the answer is yes to any of the above, don't cross post it.

Honestly, there is nothing you need to handle here. Let it go, and if you have a good reason to create a similar question on Super User, here's my advice: You've got almost two years of experience using this site that you didn't have when you first posted that question. Put that experience to good use by writing a much better question, one that is not only on-topic on SU but also well-scoped, clear, answerable, and so on. If you really still need an answer on the same topic, you must have been thinking about it a lot, so you can probably write a really great *new* question instead of cross-posting this old piece of gosa.

As for developer migration, put it out of your mind. Your question only has two favorites and 1k views; that's really not much.

Oh, and you could [probably just go ahead and post another version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244006/254929) on SU if it was really a good question that accidentally wasn't migrated. It's arguably not even cross posting when so much time has passed. But keep in mind the caveats, and consider asking on *their* meta whether your contribution will be well-received. Not this one.

Comment: Agreed.  The main reason I didn't want to delete is for those favorites--though it's only 2 people, I know I'd be irritated if I had bookmarked something for later use and it then disappeared.  I'm not concerned about rep, just trying to give some more back to the community since I've been asking a decent number of questions lately.  I'll look more at the existing information on SU and evaluate whether a new question on the topic could add value to what is already there.